# Many failed ssh logins even with password authentication off

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security

There are some bots trying to ssh (hundreds per day) all my servers at digital ocean.

On /etc/ssh/sshd_config I´ve set:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

I´ve tested to ssh from machines without the ssh key configured and I get permission denied (as expected). Those failed tries I did do not get logged.

So... How can the following be possible?

```
Aug 31 13:26:07 margarita sshd: Invalid user appfire from 219.153.15.122
Aug 31 13:26:07 margarita sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user appfire [preauth]
Aug 31 13:26:12 margarita sshd: Invalid user appfire from 219.153.15.122
Aug 31 13:26:12 margarita sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user appfire [preauth]
Aug 31 13:52:38 margarita sshd: Invalid user admin from 193.104.41.53
Aug 31 13:52:38 margarita sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Aug 31 13:53:57 kaleshi sshd: Invalid user admin from 193.104.41.53
Aug 31 13:53:57 kaleshi sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user admin [preauth]
Aug 31 13:58:46 margarita sshd: Invalid user user from 193.104.41.53
Aug 31 13:58:46 margarita sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Aug 31 14:00:03 kaleshi sshd: Invalid user user from 193.104.41.53
Aug 31 14:00:03 kaleshi sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user user [preauth]
Aug 31 14:04:48 margarita sshd: Invalid user pi from 193.104.41.53
Aug 31 14:04:48 margarita sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user pi [preauth]
Aug 31 14:06:04 kaleshi sshd: Invalid user pi from 193.104.41.53
Aug 31 14:06:04 kaleshi sshd: input_userauth_request: invalid user pi [preauth]
```

I´m going to install [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) but I need to understand first how those log entries could be generated with password authentication off

Comment: if you don't provide any key and there is no other method to try, there is nothing to log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive it's connected with

> login_grace_time

which means that sshd service will close connection when user is not authed properly in peroid of time given by directive login_grace_time. 
Since you disabled logging with password user cannot be authed with password so the connection is closed rapidly (which indicates [preauth] part in your log).
It's a good manner to install fail2ban as well as change default 22 port to something else.